# How do I turn printer online?

Tags: printing

My printer will not print all of a sudden.  Says printer is offline?  Network status is offline? The little blue wireless icon on the printer is lit up.
HP Officejet 6500 wireless printer.

Comment: Printer offline is a message you get from your computer because your computer can no longer find the printer on the network. Have you tried: 1. powering off and powering on your printer? 2. Print out network configuration from the printer config page to check the current printer IP address? (your printer IP addrress may change if you set it as DHCP)

Comment: [Solution here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Networking-and-Wireless/SOLUTION-to-your-HP-printer-going-offline-and-or-constantly/td-p/213935)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure they are both are on the same network. If  they are on the same network, take your computer and printer and plug the printer in your computer through usb. Doesn't always work but sometimes it oddly does. If all fails you have to reinstall the printer on the computer. Make sure you Uninstall the printer driver first before trying to install. If you still have the installation cd it will make the process much faster. If you have any questions just comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your network is perfectly ok and the printer is connected as supposed, it could be an issue with your snmp probe.

Go to "devices and printers"
Right click on your printer and select "printer priperties"
Click on the "port" tab
Your currently connected port is displayed amongst other available ports... Just click on configure port. 
Uncheck "smnp"

Restart your printer (if it doesn't come online in 60secs)